# Operations with bits

Tags: c, encryption, bit-manipulation, bit

program must be a cipher that has a sign in two halves (4 + 4 bits), in the first half, divide the bits into two pairs and replace their values ​​​​in the pair mutually (from 10 will be 01, and 00 will be 00, use the resulting 4 bits with the XOR function for the second half, help me find the mistake in my code, please

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char* encrypt(const char* text) {
    int len = strlen(text);
    unsigned char* encrypted = (unsigned char*) malloc(len * sizeof(unsigned char));
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        unsigned char c = text[i];
        unsigned char first_half = (c >> 4) & 0x0F;
        unsigned char second_half = c & 0x0F;
        unsigned char swapped_first_half = ((first_half & 0x03) << 2) | ((first_half & 0x0C) >> 2);
        unsigned char xor_result = swapped_first_half ^ second_half;
        encrypted[i] = (swapped_first_half << 4) | xor_result;
    }
    return encrypted;
}
 
int main() {
    unsigned char* e;
    e = encrypt("Hello world!");
    for(int i=0; i < 12;i++) printf("%x ", e[i]);
       // Expected output - 80 9c 95 95 96 11 bc 96 b9 95 9d 10
    
}
```

Comment: ANDing with 0xe (and not 0xf) seems wrong.

Comment: output still the same, but yes ending with E is wrogn F must represents that code writen in 16-bit system

Comment: OT: When encoding just 8 bits a look-up table with 256 entries would do the job much faster and the code would be more simple.

Comment: @SupportUkraine True, but remember that for **real** ciphers (those things that use a key and don't always encrypt 0x00 to 0x00) creating a data dependent lookup table is not advisable due to side channel attacks.

Answer (score 3):

Nowhere in the source code does the program do this step:

> … replace their values ​​​​in the pair mutually (from 10 will be 01, and 00 will be 00…

The program does these steps:

1. Separate the first half and the second half.
2. Swap the first two bits in the first half with the second two bits in the first half.
3. XOR the first half into the second half.
4. Reassemble the swapped first half with the XORed second half.

Step 2 should be:

2. In the four bits of the first half, separate the first two bits and the second two bits. In each of those two bits, swap the bits. (0 becomes 0, 1 becomes 2, 2 becomes 1, 3 becomes 3.) Reassemble the two pairs of bits into four bits.

Comment: Note that you can swap the two sets of bits at the same time by using shift left and right.